# Having a ChannelFactory cache, close it when channel fails?

Tags: wcf

I have cached WCF ChannelFactories per WCF contract (.NET 4, so without the Always On) so I do not have long cold starts at a calling action on the channel.

Each channel is used per call and closed per channelfactory (no cache here).

What should I do when a channel fails ? Should I close the (cached) factory and rebuild it ? Or can I leave the channelfactory cached at its place (application cache ASP.NET MVC) ?

Comment: ChannelFactory is used to create channels.  If a given channel fails, why would you close the Factory?  Just create a new channel.

Comment: That was my thought also Tim, but I couldn't read on Msdn any consequences leaving the channelfactory cached that way